# Split path (minus arrow tip) evenly

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-path

I would like to split a path evenly (in three parts) in a way that works when there is an arrow tip that hides part of the path. In other words, I would like the segments of each color to be of equal length in the following document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
    
\newcommand{\withthirdscoordinates}[1]{
    \begin{scope}
        \coordinate (n0) at (\tikzinputsegmentfirst);
        \coordinate (n3) at (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
        \coordinate (n1) at (barycentric cs:n0=2,n3=1);
        \coordinate (n2) at (barycentric cs:n0=1,n3=2);
        #1
    \end{scope}
}

\tikzset{
  mystyle/.style={
    decoration={
      show path construction,
      lineto code={
        \withthirdscoordinates{
          \draw [-, color=red] (n0) -- (n1);
          \draw [-, color=green] (n1) -- (n2);
          \draw [color=blue] (n2) -- (n3);
        }
      },
    },
    decorate
  }
}

\tikzset{
  every node/.style={circle, draw}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) at (0,0) {A};
\node (B) at (5,0) {B};
\draw[-{Triangle[open]}, mystyle] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) at (0,0) {A};
\node (B) at (5,0) {B};
\draw[-{Triangle[open, length=35pt]}, mystyle] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sounds like a meta decoration thing.

Comment: In your example, your path is just a straight line.  Is it sufficient to provide an answer that works just for single straight lines?  (polylines would be a little more complicated, and bézier curves more complicated still)

Comment: @AndrewStacey Yes, I only need to draw straight arrows

Comment: The perfect answer is this one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/623891/101651

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is very partial since it works only for horizontal straight lines, not for sloped ones.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
    
\tikzset{
  mystyle/.style={
    -{Triangle[open, length=#1]},
    decoration={
      show path construction,
      lineto code={
        \coordinate (n0) at (\tikzinputsegmentfirst);
        \coordinate (n3) at ([xshift=-#1]\tikzinputsegmentlast);
        \coordinate (n4) at (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
        \coordinate (n1) at (barycentric cs:n0=2,n3=1);
        \coordinate (n2) at (barycentric cs:n0=1,n3=2);
        \draw [-, color=red] (n0) -- (n1);
        \draw [-, color=green] (n1) -- (n2);
        \draw [-, color=blue] (n2) -- (n3);
        \draw (n3) -- (n4);
        }
      },
    decorate
  },
  mystyle/.default=5pt,
  every node/.style={circle, draw}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) at (0,0) {A};
\node (B) at (5,0) {B};
\draw[mystyle] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) at (0,0) {A};
\node (B) at (5,0) {B};
\draw[mystyle={35pt}] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

See also [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/623259/how-to-get-the-coordinates-of-the-visual-back-end-point-of-an-arrow).