# How to get the coordinates of the visual back end point of an arrow?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I tried to answer an interesting but underrated [old question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/611463/split-path-minus-arrow-tip-evenly).

To make my answer work also for sloped paths, I need the coordinates of the visual back end point of an arrow.

From the TikZ manual:
[image]
[image]

I would like to change `([xshift=-#1]\tikzinputsegmentlast)` in the following code with the coordinates of the visual back end of the arrow.

Is it possible?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
    
\tikzset{
  mystyle/.style={
    -{Triangle[open, length=#1]},
    decoration={
      show path construction,
      lineto code={
        \coordinate (n0) at (\tikzinputsegmentfirst);
        \coordinate (n3) at ([xshift=-#1]\tikzinputsegmentlast);
        \coordinate (n4) at (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
        \coordinate (n1) at (barycentric cs:n0=2,n3=1);
        \coordinate (n2) at (barycentric cs:n0=1,n3=2);
        \draw [-, color=red] (n0) -- (n1);
        \draw [-, color=green] (n1) -- (n2);
        \draw [-, color=blue] (n2) -- (n3);
        \draw (n3) -- (n4);
        }
      },
    decorate
  },
  mystyle/.default=5pt,
  every node/.style={circle, draw}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) at (0,0) {A};
\node (B) at (5,0) {B};
\draw[mystyle] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) at (0,0) {A};
\node (B) at (5,0) {B};
\draw[mystyle={35pt}] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) at (0,0) {A};
\node (B) at (5,1) {B};
\draw[mystyle={20}] (A) -- (B); 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

As you can see, now the third picture is wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The positions of the visual back end is stored in

> ```
> \csname pgf@ar@visual@\pgf@arrow@id\endcsname
> ```

with format

> ```
> {visual tip end}{visual back end}{}
> ```

So tip minus back is the distance
you want to subtract from the line.

To learn `\pgf@arrow@id`, you pass
the arrow specification to `\pgfsetarrowsend`.
For instance `\pgfsetarrowsend{Triangle[length=1cm]}`.
The function of the later command is two-fold:

- If the arrow spec has not been used before,
  it computes everything needed and caches.
- If the arrow spec has been used before,
  it sets `\pgf@arrow@id` to the old id.

Either way, you know `\pgf@arrow@id` and now
`\csname pgf@ar@visual@\pgf@arrow@id\endcsname` makes sense.
The rest is expandafter-exercise.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\makeatletter
\def\computevisuallength#1#2#3{% visual end, visual tip, dummy
    \pgf@x#1
    \pgf@y#2
    \advance\pgf@x-\pgf@y
    \xdef\visuallength{\the\pgf@x}
}
\tikzset{
  mystyle/.style={
    decoration={
      show path construction,
      lineto code={
        \coordinate (n0) at (\tikzinputsegmentfirst);
        \coordinate (n4) at (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
        \draw[dash pattern=on0off9999,-{Triangle[open, length=#1]}] (n0) -- (n4);
        {
            \pgfsetarrowsend{Triangle[open, length=#1]}% force pgf recall this arrow
            \def\pgf@arrow@hull@point{hull}%%
            \message{^^J }
            \message{^^J arrow id: pgf@arrow@id\pgf@arrow@id}
            \message{^^J hull: \csname pgf@ar@hull@\pgf@arrow@id\endcsname}
            \message{^^J tip back: \csname pgf@ar@ends@\pgf@arrow@id\endcsname}
            \message{^^J vis tip back: \csname pgf@ar@visual@\pgf@arrow@id\endcsname}
            \message{^^J etc etc}
            \message{^^J }
            \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\computevisuallength
            \csname pgf@ar@visual@\pgf@arrow@id\endcsname
        }
        \coordinate (n3) at ($(n4)!\visuallength!(n0)$);
        \coordinate (n1) at (barycentric cs:n0=2,n3=1);
        \coordinate (n2) at (barycentric cs:n0=1,n3=2);
        \draw [color=red] (n0) -- (n1);
        \draw [color=green] (n1) -- (n2);
        \draw [color=blue] (n2) -- (n3);
        }
      },
    decorate
  },
  mystyle/.default=5pt,
  every node/.style={circle, draw}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) at (0,0) {A};
\node (B) at (5,0) {B};
\draw[mystyle] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) at (0,0) {A};
\node (B) at (5,0) {B};
\draw[mystyle={35pt}] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) at (0,0) {A};
\node (B) at (5,1) {B};
\draw[mystyle={20}] (A) -- (B); 
\end{tikzpicture}

% Repeat the second arrow, can pgf recall the parameter?
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) at (0,0) {A};
\node (B) at (5,0) {B};
\draw[mystyle={35pt}] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: line before arrow is divided into three equal segments]

Comment: +1 You're the arrow master.

Comment: This is perfect, it works also with other arrow types. I can award the bounty in 7 hours.

Answer (score 5):

```tex
\coordinate (n3) at 
          ($(\tikzinputsegmentlast)!#1!(\tikzinputsegmentfirst)$);
```

works. This defines `n3` to be a coordinate along the line from segment last and segment first, and `#1` (`#1` must be a length) away from last.

**Bonus**: The code snippet below adds support for `shorten >=<length>`, as well as the use case when `#1` is a unit-less "length" (by making use of a "feature" of `pgfmath`).

```tex
\coordinate (n3) at 
          ($(\tikzinputsegmentlast)!#1+\pgf@shorten@end@additional!(\tikzinputsegmentfirst)$);
```

Full example

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  mystyle/.style={
    -{Triangle[open, length=#1]},
    decoration={
      show path construction,
      lineto code={
        \coordinate (n0) at (\tikzinputsegmentfirst);
        \coordinate (n3) at 
          ($(\tikzinputsegmentlast)!#1+\pgf@shorten@end@additional!(\tikzinputsegmentfirst)$);
        \coordinate (n4) at (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
        \coordinate (n1) at (barycentric cs:n0=2,n3=1);
        \coordinate (n2) at (barycentric cs:n0=1,n3=2);
        \begin{scope}[shorten >=0pt, arrows={-}]
          \draw[red] (n0) -- (n1);
          \draw[green] (n1) -- (n2);
          \draw[blue] (n2) -- (n3);
        \end{scope}
        % this `\draw` will add the end-of-path arrow
        \draw (n3) -- (n4);
        % control group
        \draw[help lines]
           ($ (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) + (0,.2) $) -- 
           ($ (\tikzinputsegmentlast)  + (0,.2) $);
        }
      },
    decorate
  },
  mystyle/.default=5pt,
  every node/.style={circle, draw}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (A) at (0,0) {A};
  \node (B) at (5,0) {B};
  \draw[mystyle] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (A) at (0,0) {A};
  \node (B) at (5,0) {B};
  \draw[mystyle={35pt}] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (A) at (0,0) {A};
  \node (B) at (5,1) {B};
  \draw[mystyle={20}] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (A) at (0,0) {A};
  \node (B) at (5,1) {B};
  \draw[mystyle={20}, shorten >=10pt] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Remark: To support `curve to`, I guess something similar to `\pgf@prep@curved(start|end)` is required.

Comment: +1 In the old question, the arrow head was given separate from the tricolor style. I made some experiments with applying three actions in the line of `decoration={lineto, pre=moveto, pre length=0.66*\pgfmetadecoratedpathlength}, decorate, blue` but I can not make it work with an arrow head.

Comment: @hpekristiansen I think the decoration never takes the path shortening into account, as shown in `pgfmanual` sec. 3.12 "Adding the Snaked Line and Multi-Line Text". Hence a complete answer to the old question really requires retrieving or re-calculating the shorten length.

Comment: Thank you @muzimuzhiZ. Actually, this solves the original problem but doesn't give exactly the answer to this question (the coordinates of the visual back end). I think you should answer the original question. I'll wait a bit before accepting your answer to see if someone else gives another solution.

Comment: Coordinate `n3` is the one you need. If you prefer a standalone solution that works outside the decoration,`\pgf@prepare@end@of@path` can be a starter. I will try this way, maybe tomorrow.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Yes, but coordinate `n3` is calculated using the length passed as an argument, it is not general. For example, if I change the arrow shape, the default doesn't work anymore. Thank you if you have time to dedicate to this tomorrow.

Comment: True. I overlooked that `#1` is also passed to `length=#1`.

Comment: I'm trying the possibility of first shorten the subpath(s) for arrow(s) then do decorations. That'll take more time.